# How to speed up data stream (with graph6 format) reading?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I attempt to filter connected graphs with 8 vertices, 14 edges, and matching number three using the '[geng](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/nauty/)' tool and [IGraphM](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html).

First way:

```
<< IGraphM`;
AbsoluteTiming[
  Length[Select[IGImport["!geng 8 14 -c", "Nauty"], 
    IGMatchingNumber[#] == 3  &]]]
```

{0.465577, 48}

It shows that the code just takes 0.465s.

However, this approach has a drawback, namely, if there are numerous graphs, it consumes a lot of memory. So, we thought of using iteration. Thus, I attempted the method below, but the **speed significantly decreased** (a difference of roughly several tens of times). Is there a compromise solution?

```
geng = StartProcess[{"geng", "8", "14", 
    "-c"}];
AbsoluteTiming[
 Length[output = 
   Reap[While[(line = ReadLine[geng]) =!= EndOfFile, 
      gr = ImportString[line, "Graph6"]; 
      If[IGMatchingNumber[gr] == 3 , Sow[gr]]]][[2, 1]]]]
```

{8.41595, 48}